# How to add Images to .jar file in Intellij

Tags: java, image, intellij-idea

I've been trying to add Images to my jar file for some time now I've searched many ways but nothing works. Many threads say various methods that don't work and its frustrating me.

*I have the problem where when I run it with Intellij the images render well*, but **when I build it into a .jar file all the images don't render**

My normal code is written like this:

```
> randomIcon = new ImageIcon("src/"+ randomChoice + ".png");
```

I've tried to do this but it returns as a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
randomIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/" + randomChoice + ".png").toString());
```

> I'm not sure what I'm doing, I'm just very confused
> [This is my
> project folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4AFQ.png)

**I'd be very happy if someone says a simple solution or tell me what I'm doing wrong!**
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The location of resources is not correct. It should be under the /src/main/resources

Then you can use following to read the file.

```
  InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");

  InputStream is = JavaClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt");
```

Reference :
https://mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html

Comment: I don't understand, (/src/main/resources)  part is a bit confusing, Can you elaborate further? The links are a bit confusing so I'll do some further research into them. Thank you!